# Flickring issue in Textbox when using auto complete in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

i am using custom auto source to the text box. But the problem is, when i am entering key , if the suggestion list is high then the textbox flickers before showing suggestion.

```
private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtSearch.Text != "")
        {

            string templateSearchTxt = txtSearch.Text;

            foreach (String template in templateName) // templateName contains list of string
            {
                if (template.ToUpper().StartsWith(templateSearchTxt.ToUpper()))
                {
                    suggestion.Add(template);                       

                }
            }
        } 
    }
```

I have declared following code on form load event

```
        suggestion = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        txtSearch.AutoCompleteCustomSource = suggestion;
        txtSearch.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
        txtSearch.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
```

Answer (score 1):

I will seriously encourage you to use a Combobox with its [AutoCompleteMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.autocompletemode) set to `Suggest` and attach the autocomplete list to it (as its [AutoCompleteSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.autocompletesource)). It'll performt way better than your textchanged event listener.